# Base class public function and Virtual

Tags: c++, inheritance

Can I call the base class method from the virtual methods of the derived class ??

```
Class A {

public:
  virtual ~A();
  virtual void some_function() {};
  int Foo();
}

Class B : public A {

public:
   B();
   virtual void Bar() const = 0;
}

// B.cpp

void B::Bar() const {
x = Foo();
}
```

Can i call like above ?? Getting the following error:

error: no matching member function for call to 'Foo'
not viable: no known conversion from B to A for object argument.

Answer (score 0):

First you said `B::Bar` was abstract and then you implemented it. That makes no sense. You need to remove that `= 0` on the end.